# Sharepoint HTML Email outputs Junk characters for "Domain\Username" values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, html-email, sharepoint-workflow

I recently created a workflow on Sharepoint 2010, which has a step to shoot out emails to the desired users.

The content of the email body is formatted in HTML and I need the sharepoint to send me the details of the User who creates/changes a particular item.

However, when i receive the email in my Inbox, I see that it is in **Domain\Username** format, but I also see some junk characters appended to the same.

For Example. I receive the following output for the sharepoint Lookup [Current Item: Requestors] (As String)

11;#DOMAIN\USERNAME1;#9;#DOMAIN\USERNAME2

Could someone help me in letting me know on how to eliminate these junk characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try "As Display Name" instead of "As String" in the Lookup [Current Item: Requestors].

And btw it is not junk. These the IDs of the users :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, When I try the **"Display Name, Semicolon delimited"** option, the Workflow fails and gives me an Error - **"Coercion Failed: Input cannot be null for this coercion."**.

Please Advice on this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are the display names of your AD in the format "<Name>, <Last Name>"? Have you tried other options besides the Display Name, Semicolon delimited?

Comment: The Display Names of my AD are in the format "<Lastname>, <Name>".

Also, I have tried all other options but still get the same issue.

Comment: Where do you get your "user typed" value from? is it a field of type Person / Group?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you cannot use "As String" as it includes the items IDs and does not include the users email address, username or login information. You need to the use one of the Semicolon Delimited options in order to use this information.

Now, as for "Coercion Failed: Input cannot be null for this coercion." once you make the change, you can not use a delimited option and then have the field be empty. To get around this set the field as required or leave it as a string with the item IDs being shown.

The same issues arise if you want to use the people picker and then use that field to email those users, you have to use "Email Addresses, Semicolon Delimited" and the field must have a user selected or it will run in to the coercion error.