# Sharepoint HTML Email outputs 5;#, 4;#, etc characters

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, html-email

I have a problem with SharePoint 2010 email sending. I have a list with a  column (single line of text), for example the value is 'Apple'.

I have a workflow, what starts when the new item is saved and the email going out includes the [%Current Item:Apple%] lookup. The problem is, when the email arrives it shows '5;#Apple'.

I found this QA - [Sharepoint HTML Email outputs Junk characters for "Domain\Username" values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464271/sharepoint-html-email-outputs-junk-characters-for-domain-username-values) - but with the single line of text you cannot modify the "Return field as" since it's just a string.

How can you remove this extra character, the ID of the item?

Thanks.

added as it's possibly important: the source list is a standard list, but in the new item form you use it with a Resources Field, a resource list: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-HA101810595.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this post when researching a similar problem.  Here's how I finally got it to work:

- Create a new workflow variable with data type string.
- Set the value of the variable to Current Item:Apple (the name of your Resources field).
- Use the new variable in your email, and when doing so you will have many more options to return the field as (I used "Lookup Values, Comma Delimited", which just lists the names of the resources).